# Getting Context from Activity in Kotlin fragment

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, sharedpreferences

How do I get context from Activity in a fragment in Kotlin. I know, in Java you can call getActivity()

Answer (score 1):

To get the `Context` in the `Fragment` from AndroidX support library you can use method [`requireContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext())

If you need an `Activity` instance to which your `Fragment` is attached, use the [`requireActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireActivity()) method.

*Note:  These methods will only work when the fragment is attached to some activity. Otherwise they will throw an error.*